Group lettering of dunn.test outcome relative to the mean values of the variables
How to modify the following r script so that the variable having the highest mean should get the initial letter and so on?
# Load required packages
library(dunn.test)
library(multcompView)

# Sample data (replace with your actual data)
data <- data.frame(
  value = c(5.5, 6.1, 7.0, 6.0, 6.5, 7.1, 7.9, 
            6.3,6.4),
  group = factor(c("NSDG", "NSDG", "NSDG",  
                   "Bhima", "Bhima", "Bhima",
                   "NSLG", "NSLG", "NSLG"))
)

# Step 1: Perform Kruskal-Wallis test
kruskal_result <- kruskal.test(value ~ group, 
    data = data)

# Check if Kruskal-Wallis test is significant
cat("Kruskal-Wallis test is significant. Performing 
    Dunn's post-hoc test.\n")
  
# Step 2: Perform Dunn's post-hoc test
dunn_result <- dunn.test(data$value, data$group, 
    method = "bonferroni")
  
# Extract pairwise adjusted p-values with proper 
# naming for each comparison
comparisons <- dunn_result$comparisons
p_values <- dunn_result$P.adjusted
  
# Step 3: Create a named vector for p-values with 
# correct naming
names(p_values) <- comparisons  
    # Assign comparison names to p-values
  
# Filter out only the pairs that have one comparison
p_values <- p_values[names(p_values) != ""]
  
# Ensure names are in the format "Group1-Group2"
names(p_values) <- gsub(" - ", "-", names(p_values))
  
# Step 4: Generate grouping letters
group_letters <- 
    multcompView::multcompLetters(p_values)
  
# Display results
print(group_letters)

